# jQuery Datatable pagination shows wrong information

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables

I am new to jQuery  DataTable, and in my case pagination enabled. Following are the settings I am using:

```
        pageLength: 50,
        lengthChange: false,
        searching: true,
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        "StateSave": true,
```

So basically let us say the serverside query(using Hibernate) returns 500 records. Then using Hibernate setFirstResult() and SetMaxResults() I am managing the Page frame to render on view side. Now since searching is enabled, I want to filter on the page frame using the text entered in the search box. Let me explain what I am trying to do. So for example let us say that the serverside query returned 500 records for the first time, and then I return the first page for the view to render. 
It shows correctly as expected for the first page as follows:

"Showing 1 to 50 of 500 entries"

But then when I type some text in the searchbox it goes wrong. So say for example after the search is submitted the, server creates a query which again has returned 500 records. As usual I will return the page frame. But as soon as I am about to send the frame for  the view to render, this time I am searching inside the page frame(List of DTOs) for the search text. So the page frame will now have say 30 records(List of DTOs of size 30). So I will send a page frame of 30 records to the View. But just before that I  want to manipulate recordsTotal and recordsFiltered . In this case I expect to see the information on first page as:

Showing 1 to 30 of 500 entries

instead it shows as:

Showing 1 to 50 of 500 entries

So even though, the first page shows only 30 records, the information displayed is wrong.

In summary my requirement is that the page frame which is about to be returned to View, I need to filter inside the page frame using the search text. This narrowed page frame which the user is viewing should show correct page information based on the amount of records in that page frame. But as seen currently, it always shows "Showing 1 to 50 of 500 entries". So I am sure I have some confusion regarding recordsTotal and recordsFiltered. What should I do so that I can see "Showing 1 to 30 of 500 entries" in this case?. Actually searching on the client side is working for me for views which do not have pagination enabled( serverSide: false). But since I have pagination(and so  serverSide: true), I was trying something which I have explained.

Thanks

Comment: So basically my requirement is that I could control the displayed info

Comment: I think I should be able to show custom "info":   something like "Total records filtered on this page=30" instead of the default message "Showing 1... entries". At server-side I already know how many records are there finally in the page frame( 30 in my example) . So I should be able to show this custom message  using "language": {  "info::  }   ?